# how to create more than one files in SD card?

Tags: android

i tried the code below!!every time it replaces contents from file "textfile.txt" i want the user to add files to SD card with name which they have entered as "filename" 
i have registered onclick listener on save button
Code:

```
            EditText filename =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.filename);

             EditText filecontent =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.filecontent);

                public void onClick(View view) 

                      { 

                       String str = filename.getText().toString();
          String str2= filecontent.getText().toString();


                    file sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File directory = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() +"/MyFiles");
            directory.mkdirs();



                    File file = new File(directory,"textfile.txt");
                    file.createNewFile();


                    FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);


                    osw.write(str);
            osw.write("   ");
            osw.write(str2);
           osw.flush();
            osw.close();
                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change it to
File file = new File(directory,str+".txt");
it will store file S THE NAME GIVEN BY USER!!!

Answer (score 1):

If i understood your question correctly, here is your solution:

change `"textfile.txt"` inside `File file = new File(directory,"textfile.txt");` 
to `filename`.

Final result shouldlook : `File file = new File(directory,filename);`

Comment: its showing error for your code "The constructor File(File, EditText) is undefined"

Answer (score 0):

Well then you have to give each file a unique name.

Comment: i want user to given filename in text box  and that would be the file name of file saved in SD card!!!